# MySQL auto_increment setting error problem

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

everyone!

Currently, I am making a new schema using MySQL, and trying to alter auto_increment from 100.
But sometimes when I set auto_increment from 100, it starts from 101, not 100.
Is there anybody who knows why???

When I set auto_increment = 100 for the first time in the same schema, it works well.
But when I try to alter auto_increment = 200, 300, or 1000, it doesn't start from the number I want.
It starts from 201, 301, or 1001. I just started to study MySQL so I need help to figure out why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. After I alter the auto_increment, the next row I insert has that ID.

Comment: Is it possible you're altering to an ID that's already in use? It won't reuse an ID, so it will keep incrementing until it gets to one that's not used yet.

Comment: I think you need to explain why you need to change the AUTO INCREMENT parameters at all. AUTO INCREMENT is intended to create a unique identifier for a row. It's not intended to be changed or fiddled with.

Comment: It was just for my practice. I just noticed when I set `alter table <name> auto_increment = 1000` and `@@auto_increment_increment = 1`, it worked well. but when I tried to set `@@auto_increment_increment` to a different number like 5, the problem occurred.

Comment: This is "by design". [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DpDMSYUG). This cannot be treated as a bug because autoincrement provides/guarantees: (1) then next generated value is above any existing value (2) if the attribute was not altered then next generated value is above any previously generated value. The rule 1 also provides the generated value uniqueness when a lot of concurrent generations are performed. That's all. Hence the effect observed is an implementation feature only. In general you'd never access/look at AI PK value, it is used for unique row identifying only (in FKs and JOINs).

Answer (score 0):

The product is behaving as documented.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html says:

> `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>
> An integer or floating-point column can have the additional attribute
> `AUTO_INCREMENT`. When you insert a value of NULL (recommended) or 0
> into an indexed `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the column is set to the next
> sequence value. **Typically this is value+1,** where value is the largest
> value for the column currently in the table. `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequences
> begin with 1.

(emphasis mine)

So if you want the next value to start with 100 for example, you need to `ALTER TABLE <name> AUTO_INCREMENT=99`.

Comment: Thank you! but I just noticed when I set `alter table <name> auto_increment = 1000` and `@@auto_increment_increment = 1`, it worked well. **but when I tried to set @@auto_increment_increment to a different number like 5, the problem occurred.** Could you please check this out too? I don't know if it will be automatically solved if I study more about SQL.

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you set the increment to 5?

Comment: when I set auto_increment=1000, and @@auto_increment_increment=5, I expected to happen 1000, 1005, 1010...

Comment: But if the auto_increment is currently set to 1000, the next row inserted will be given the id 1000 + the increment.